# why this exception FileItemStream$ItemSkippedException?

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

in a gwt web application.
I have to send a file and some parameter attached to it.

on ServerSide

```
try {

        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();

        FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();


            if (item.isFormField()) {

                String fieldName=item.getFieldName();
                String fieldValue = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
                System.out.println(" chk  " +fieldName +"  =  "+ fieldValue);
            } else {
                stream = item.openStream();
                fileName = item.getName();
                mimetype = item.getContentType();
                int c;
                while ((c = stream.read()) != -1) { 
                  System.out.print((char) c); 
                    }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("out of try");
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nRead;
    while ((nRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        System.out.println("lenth111" +nRead);
        output.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
    }
    System.out.println("lenth" +nRead);
    output.flush();
```

with this code i can read the stream.
and also on console **"out of try"** is also printed

And finally on `while ((nRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)`
 line i got a Warning

WARNING: /UploadFileServlet: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream$ItemSkippedException.

How to solve this problem.??

Comment: Hi GameBuilder and Thomas Broyer, Did you find a solution on that? Because i've been getting the same problem for days. Please, could anyone help us? Thank you

Comment: hey, iam also looking for the same. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer a bit late but I had the same problem.

Why you get that exception: The JavaDocs of ItemSkippedException explain a little bit:

*This exception is thrown, if an attempt is made to read data from the InputStream, which has been returned by FileItemStream.openStream(), after Iterator.hasNext() has been invoked on the iterator, which created the FileItemStream.*

You are using the InputStream *stream* outside the while loop which causes the problem because another iteration is called which closes (skips) the file InputStream you try to read from.

Solution: Use the InputStream inside the while loop. If you need all form-fields before processing the file, ensure you set it in the right order on client side. First all fields, last the file. For example using the JavaScript FormData:

```
var fd = new window.FormData();

fd.append("param1", param1);
fd.append("param2", param2);

// file must be last parameter to append
fd.append("file", file);
```

And on server side:

```
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    InputStream stream = item.openStream();

    // the order of items is given by client, first form-fields, last file stream
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        String name = item.getFieldName();
        String value = Streams.asString(stream);
        // here we get the param1 and param2
    } else {
        String filename = item.getName();
        String mimetype = item.getContentType();

        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int nRead;
        while ((nRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("lenth111" +nRead);
            output.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
        }
        System.out.println("lenth" +nRead);
        output.flush(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, I wish it were possible to take it outside the iterator loop.

Comment: This causes a OutOfMemoryError for large file upload. Which doesn't occur when we use parseRequest(request). Is there a way around ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To solve it, I had to break out of the while loop after reading the last item:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams;

final String ID = "id";
final String FILE_NAME = "fileName";
final String APIKEY = "apikey";

DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);      

String id = null;
String apikey = null;
String fileName = null;
InputStream stream = null;

FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
outer: while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
    switch (item.getFieldName()) {
    case ID:
        id = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
        break;
    case APIKEY:
        apikey = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
        break;
    case FILE_NAME:
        fileName = item.getName();
        stream = item.openStream();
        break outer;
    }
}
```

`break outer;` is the line that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you accessing the data from the formfield, after that skip that iteration.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();


            if (item.isFormField()) {

                String fieldName=item.getFieldName();
                String fieldValue = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
                System.out.println(" chk  " +fieldName +"  =  "+ fieldValue);
                continue;//// this line you need to add. then it will close the FileItemStream object for that iteration
            } else {
                stream = item.openStream();
                fileName = item.getName();
                mimetype = item.getContentType();
                int c;
                while ((c = stream.read()) != -1) { 
                  System.out.print((char) c); 
                    }
            }
        }
```